# トップページの「サイト統計情報」で「訪問者数」が "0" と表示される

Tags: バグ, 調査中

2023/12/04 現在、トップページの右側に表示される「サイト統計情報」のうち、「訪問者/日」が "0" になっています。
(少なくとも「質問」はカウントアップしているのを確認済みです)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 4):

Google アナリティクスが UA から GA4 へ変更された際に、いくつかの統計データがサポートされなくなったことが影響しているかもしれません。2022年10月に投稿されたスレッド「[Can we have a little notice letting people know that analytics changed after May 10, 2022?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379947)」へ、[次のような回答](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/392979)が投稿されていました。

> **TL;DR; We have removed Universal Analytics data throughout our sites because of the inaccuracy and eventual lack of support from Google.**
>
> （中略）
>
> - Remove the following data points from pages that include data from Universal Analytics (`/site-analytics`,
>   `/site-analytics/traffic-sources`, `/admin/analytics`, and
>   [stackexchange.com/sites#traffic][3]):
>
>   - Traffic
>   - Visits/day
>   - Number of new visits
>   - Traffic sources
>   - Referring sites
>   - Search engines
>   - Search keywords
>
> （後略）

Comment: 改めて確認すると、モデレーターのみアクセスできる `/admin/analytics` では訪問者数も記録されている様子です。参照してくれた [コメント欄でも言及されていますが](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379947/can-we-have-a-little-notice-letting-people-know-that-analytics-changed-after-may#comment1314228_392979) 、訪問者数/日 (visits/day) の列自体を削除すべきなのかもしれませんね (いずれにせよスタッフの対応が必要そうです)。